# Dirichlet's Kernel, Identity for complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

It is easy to prove that $ 1/2 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \cos(kt) = \frac{\sin(n+1/2)t}{2\sin(t/2)} $ for every real number t.

I know also that this identity doesn't hold for complex numbers but i can't find out why.
Is there any hint you have in mind ?

Comment: Where did you read that it is not defined for complex numbers ?

Comment: Well, i didn't. Our professor said it, but didn't elaborated it. 
If you'll search about it you will see that everywhere, that identity is defined on real numbers only. If it where on complex numbers as also(something so powerful) somebody would have mentioned it. I understand that what i'm saying is not a proof. You may have to trust me. I just don't have a proof in mind.

Comment: Both sides define analytical functions of t wherever they are defined (the left hand side is obviously defined on all of C, and so the RHS can be continued everywhere sin(t/2) vanishes). I'd guess the reason why we always restrict to real t is because there isn't any added value to consider it for complex t.

Comment: I understand, although i don't believe that's the case this time. 
Thanks, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

In your question, $t$ is real because it is a value between $[0,2\pi)$ since it is an angle so it wouldn't make any sense to plug on some $a+bi$ unless you plugged in $\arg(a+bi)$.

---

Dirichlet kernel is generally defined as
$$
D_N(\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{-n}^ne^{in\theta} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum(\cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta))
$$
Now $\theta$ is angle and $n$ is an integer so I don't see why you would insert a complex number for those two values. However, if we let $\theta =\pi/2$, then
$$
D_N(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{-n}^n\cos(n\pi/2)+i\sin(n\pi/2)
$$
Now we are summing real and complex numbers in the Dirichlet kernel but the result will be real. For $n=1$, we get 
$$
D_N(\theta) = (-i + 1 + i)/(2\pi) = 1/(2\pi)
$$
Now, let's make sure what I said is the Dirichlet kernel agrees with what you have. Since your definition excludes $2\pi$, I will as well to show that the definitions are equivalent.
\begin{align}
D_N(\theta) &= \sum_{-n}^ne^{in\theta}\\
&= 1+\sum_{k=0}^ne^{ik\theta} + \sum_{k=1}^ne^{-ik\theta}\\
&= 1 + 2\sum_{k=0}^n\cos(k\theta)\\
&=1/2 + \sum_{k=0}^n\cos(k\theta)
\end{align}

Comment: This is very confusing. Why wouldn't it make sense to talk about $\sin z$ where $z$ is a complex number?

Comment: @mrf At this time, Dirichlet was examining pointwise convergence of the nth partial sum of the solution to laplace equations in a disc. So he was looking $\sum e^{in\theta}$ from the solution of laplaces equation so theta was an angle.

Comment: Sure, I'm well aware of the history. Still, the (correct) equality certainly makes sense, and is true, also for a complex $t$, which was the OP's question. Regardless of where the original motivation comes from.

Comment: If we forget about Dirichlet's Kernel, and let's confine ourselves to that identity i have given. Does it hold for complex number as well? (regardless the meaning of it) If not, there has to be an anti-proof about it. For instance if i put n=1 and t=i, if my math is right, it holds.

Comment: Moreover, one can simply notice that if you were to prove this equation for complex numbers you can't take the real part of $D_N(θ)$. Cos(nθ) for θ complex is not a real number.

Comment: The meaning of cos(t) is $(e^{it}+e^{-it})/2$ regardless of whether or not t is real. Analytic continuation tells you it's the only way to define cos(t) as an analytical function for complex t. For instance $cos(it)=cosh(t)$.

Comment: @mrf in the sum, we have $e^{in\theta}$. If we write $z=e^{i\theta}$, we have a complex number $z$ but the argument, $\theta$, of $z=a+bi$ is $\arctan(b/a)\in\mathbb{R}$. That is, the theta in the Dirichlet kernel is real.

Answer (score 0):

I think, i get to see why it's not. Consider N=1, t=πi for the identity i have given.

Thank you for your time everyone!